# How do I reorder a doubly linked list to match the order of an array with the same elements?

Tags: java, arrays, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to update the order of my doubly linked list based on an array with the same elements in the updated order.

For example if I have:

```
cat->dog->rabbit->panda
```

And I want to reorder to have the order of the array:

```
String[] pets = {"dog", "rabbit", "panda", "cat"};
```

For context: I am new to Java and programming in general so not sure how to do so. Essentially, what I am doing is that I shuffled the elements of a seating arrangement and the doubly linked list is a non-shuffled version of those students. I just want to update the doubly linked list to match the order of the new shuffled version. I want a function that can do so.

I have methods to access the last and first elements of the doubly linked list and the ability to go left or right from one element. I want to do this with elementary knowledge, without using maps and stuff. Sorry if it sounds like a hassle, I just want to understand what's happening!

Comment: Could you just build a new linked list?

Comment: Unfortunately not, for the task at hand I want it to remain the same.

Comment: Re: "my doubly linked list": Is this an instance of `java.util.LinkedList`, or your own custom doubly-linked-list class? If the latter, then -- what operations does it provide?

Comment: It's custom, it has all the abilities as a normal one would I suppose. They are just modified to meet the nature of my project.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add more context so we know what kind of answer you're looking for? For instance, are you new to Java or to programming in general? What concepts do you know? Do you want to see how a sort function works rather than using a built-in one? etc.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried any code yet as I do not know where to start. I considered using loops to iterate but I don't that would work.

Answer (score 1):

If your linked list class has the same operations as a standard `LinkedList`, you can create a map of pets to their indices in the array:

```
Map<String, Integer> arrayIndices =
    IntStream.range(0, pets.length)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> pets[i], i -> i));
```

Then sort the list with a custom comparator that sorts by array index:

```
linkedList.sort(Comparator.comparing(arrayIndices::get));
```

Comment: Thank you but is there a way to do so without using maps and stuff, i am a beginner so I don't know a lot yet and I want the code to make sense to me. Like someway that can have more code but uses simpler ways? Appreciate the help!